# Bootstrap push-pull and keep columns in same order?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been reading about the push and pull classes in bootstrap, and need to use them, but I'm having some issues. It seems that the default behavior is to rearrange the columns when pushing/pulling.

[Example here](http://codepen.io/Schmalzy/pen/iJdgD) shows that the on mobile, Column A displays first, but on desktop, Column B displays first. How can I change this so that Column A displays first on both mobile and desktop? I have a logo in what should be the left/top column, and paragraphs in the right/bottom column.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Column A</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Column B</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pushing and pulling is specifically for reordering columns, your pulling column b in front of column a in your example

Comment: You don't need to use push pull, just simply use col-sm-6. You should get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use push/pull to make column A appear first.  Remove the push/pull and the A will appear before B, and B will wrap below on a smaller screen.  The `sm` `md` `lg` will influence WHEN wrapping occurs.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Column A</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Column B</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you need the push and pull? if it was just 
`div class='col-sm-6 col-xs-12'` for each div it would work as you want

Comment: I'm a PHP developer and had a Bootstrap site dumped on me. I'm trying to figure out someone else's code.

Comment: Well give this a try, that should be what you're looking for